# Python threading and handing over values

Tags: python

Im trying to update threads which continuously run with new values every now and then.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, num):
        #testing reasons
        self.num = num

    def printloop(self, num):
        self.num = num
        #running is set to True sometime in the beginning   
        while running:
            print(self.num)
            time.sleep(3)
        if not running:
            print("finished")
    def setnum(self, num):
        self.num = num
```

I create threads like this:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=test.printloop,args=("1"))
```

This works and prints the proper arg.

But how can I update single threads with new values - if needed? Not all of the threads might need to be updated. The setnum method in my class there is obviously not working since it would update the value for all of the threads.

Do I need to limit the thread lifetime and join and wait for them to finish. Then recreating them with new values? 
Or should I define a variable for each thread - how do I do that dynamically?
Or is there a better way im not seeing?
Thanks!

Edit:

I suppose i'll end up with something like:

```
test1 = Test(1)
..
test5 = Test(5)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=test1.printloop,args=("1"))
t5 = threading.Thread(target=test5.printloop,args=("5"))
```

and then use a method on each to set the Values?

Comment: What is `run`? something that constantly goes on in background? or some task that can be finished?

Comment: I would like it to run constantly in the background - however I could set a timer on them to re-run them with new values.. My preferred method - if viable - would be to update the running threads without stopping or recreating them.

Comment: test1.setnum('new value') modifies only test1.num. Be careful with the way you initialize args though. It should be args = ('1',) because args is a tuple. So args = ('123') will throw an error because printloop will be called with three arguments '1', '2' and '3'

Answer (score 0):

For single integer values you can make `Test` a subclass of thread (and have `run` call `printloop`). Then other threads can call `setnum` safely. Due to the GIL and the fact that you are setting a single value this is safe, if you were doing a more complex update you would have to wrap `setnum` and the inner loop in `printloop` in a lock to prevent race conditions.

EDIT: A simple example

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

class Output(Thread):

    def __init__(self, num):
        super(Output, self).__init__()
        self.num = num
        self.running = False

    def run(self):
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            print self.num
            sleep(1)

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False

    def set_num(self, num):
        self.num = num

output = Output(0)
output.start()
sleep(3)
output.set_num(1)
sleep(3)
output.stop()
output.join()
```

Comment: AFAIK, setting an int is not an atomic operation, because it can be written on more than one byte, that means that the thread can be interrupted in the middle of setting the int, and then you've got yourself a race condition.

Comment: Python's GIL means that you can't corrupt Python data internally, so when you set an int the whole int will be set. If this were in a lower level language then yes there's a risk there.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean steve. Can you give me an example? Do you mean doing something like: threading.Thread.test = Test(123) ?